# Lottie working on an Emulator But not on real Device

Tags: android, react-native, android-animation, react-navigation-v5, lottie

I have `lottie` library in my project built on `react-native`. followed [These installation steps on an android](https://bestofreactjs.com/repo/airbnb-lottie-react-native-react-react-native-awesome-components), but to my surprise the animation works on fine on `emulator` but not on the real `device`.

I created a `js file`  named `MyLottie.js` and have the following `code`

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import Modal from 'react-native-modal';

import LottieView from 'lottie-react-native';

const MyLottie = ({...props}) => {
  return (
    <Modal
      backdropOpacity={0.0}
      animationType={'slide'}
      transparent={true}
      isVisible={props.isvisible}>
      <LottieView
        autoSize={false}
        // style={{width: 100, height: 100}}
        source={require('./LottieFiles/paperplane.json')}
        loop={true}
        autoPlay={true}
      />
    </Modal>
  );
};

export default MyLottie;
```

and then used `MyLottie.js` on another screen like this, a code snippet:

```
... //some other code snippets here
return(
<View>
... //some other code snippets here
 <MyLottie isvisible={loading} />
</View>
)
```

using `npx react-native run-android --variant=release` command, this works fine on `emulator` and the `lottie` animation is okay but when I use that command on real device, and app is installed. `lottie` doesn't animate at all. just dormant. what is wrong here?
additionally, on the `terminal` there are some warning deprecations and so on, including warnings regarding `lottie`, is this affecting? if it is affecting why it is working fine on `emulator`but not `real device`. Here is the warnings.

> Gradle detected a problem with the following location: 'D:\myproject\lottieproj'. Reason: Task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets' uses this output of task ':lottie-react-native:writeReleaseAarMetadata' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.2/userguide/validation_problems.html#implicit_dependency for more details about this problem.

as the above mentions,

> This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed

if that is the case, is it possible to lead an incorrect result only to `real device` but not on an `emulator`

How can I solve this?